# Where are VHDL type cast functions defined?

Tags: vhdl, vhdl-2008, typecast

In VHDL one can cast one type to another using the name of the other type e.g

```
signal x : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal y : signed(7 downto 0);
...
y <= signed(x)
```

Here we use the type as if it was name of a function. Where exactly are these "cast functions" defined and why are they confused with the type name?

Comment: It's not a cast it's a type conversion , e.g. EEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.6 Type conversions "type_conversion ::= type_mark (expression ) ", an inherent *basic operation* (5. Types 5.1 General). There are rules (9.3.6) requiring types be closely related. Array types signed and std_logic_vector are closely related both having the same dimensionality and same element base type. Unrelated types would require conversion functions (e.g. to_signed found in IEEE package numeric_std).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`Signed`" and "`unsigned`" are declared as "`SUBTYPE`" of "`std_logic_vector`", there is no need to declare cast functions.

It's a bit like in C when writing "`(signed long)var`"

Comment: I see, so this is the difference between cast and conversion function.

Comment: Prior to -2008 signed and unsigned are types. In -2008 and -2019 they are resolved subtypes of types unresolved_signed and unresolved_unsigned not std_logic_vector.